# iOS7 - 20px gap after keyboard is dismissed on any UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

I'm developing an iOS7 app in Xcode5 and everytime i dismiss the keyboard of a UITextField, the entire window of the app shifts by 20px.  This happens on both an iPad and iPhone.  Does anybody have an idea why this might be the case?  I tried setting the origin of the controller view back to 0,0 after the dismissal but this makes no difference.

Edit:  I would like to also note that I am using custom view containment and not using UINavigationController anywhere in the project.

Edit#2:  I also just realized that if I set the origin of the following to 0,0, the view shifts back into place: self.view.superview.superview.superview  (dont ask me how I figured that out)